# "unable to open buffer file" sybase isql error

Tags: sybase, isql

When trying to open sybase ISQL tool we get error as "unable to open buffer file".

Trying from LINUX RHL. Command used is as below

`isql`

Error got is as below

`unable to open buffer file`

Answer (score 0):

Temp Directory might be full. Check temp directory space `df -kh /tmp`